# object_id returns null with least permission sql authentication user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

When I run the below as sa or a user with sysadmin role.

```
Select object_id('MySchemaName.MyTableName')
```

I get a value

If I run the same under a very low privileged sql-authentication account

```
Select object_id('MySchemaName.MyTableName')
```

I get null.

I cannot figure out the permission I need.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 You need ANY permission on the object.

Answer (score 0):

As per Sean Lange's comment:

```
GRANT SELECT ON MySchemaName.MyTableName TO MySqlAuthLowBallAccount
```

fixed it.

Thanks